# Complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve this question, but I think I am missing some important detail about eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I get a really hairy matrix and I have no idea on how to compute its inverse matrix.

Let $A \in M_4(R)$ a real matrix and $T:C^4 \to C^4$ the complex linear operator with matrix A (relative to the canonical basis of $C^4$). If $i$ is eigenvalue of $T$ and $(-i,1-i,1,0)$ and $(0,1+i,0,2)$ are eigenvectors associated with $i$, then, evaluate $A^{15}$.

I know that since $A \in M_4(R)$, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue associated with $v$, then $\bar \lambda$ is an eigenvalue associated with $\bar v$. Ok, using this information, I get a matrix $M \in M_4(C)$ which is really complicated to deal with (I am trying to compute $A^n=MD^nM^{-1}$).

Comment: Note that $i^{15}=-i$ and $(-i)^{15}=i$. Thus $A^{15}=-A$. By taking conjugates, you have both eigenvalues and all four eigenvectors, so you can evaluate $A$ (though it is a bit tedious).

Comment: Yes, I think that is the point of this question!! But how can you say that $A^{15} = -A$ from $i^{15}=-i$ and $(-i)^{15}=i$??

Comment: Look at the eigendecompositions of $A$ and $A^{15}$. The $M$ and $M^{-1}$ factors are the same and the $D$ factors should differ only by a sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A v_j=\lambda_j v_j$ for $j=1,2,3,4$. You should be able to show that if $Q=[v_1\:v_2\:v_3\:v_4]$ and $D$ is the $4\times 4$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4$ (from top-left to bottom-right), then $$AQ=[Av_1\:Av_2\:Av_3\:Av_4]=[\lambda_1v_1\:\lambda_2v_2\:\lambda_3v_3\:\lambda_4v_4]=QD.$$

Thus, if the columns of $Q$ are linearly independent, then $A=QDQ^{-1},$ and powers of $A$ are straightforward to calculate.

As for how to *find* $Q^{-1},$ you can start with the augmented matrix $[Q\mid I_4],$ where $I_4$ is the $4\times 4$ identity matrix, and perform row operations until the augmented matrix has the form $[I_4\mid B].$ Then $B$ is exactly $Q^{-1},$ as you should be able to verify.

---

**Added**: The *really* good news is that you need not calculate $Q^{-1}$ at all! However, it depends on making two slick observations. Namely, for this particular matrix $A$, we have:

- $D^2=-I_4$
- $A^2=Q^{-1}D^2Q$

Putting these observations together, we see that $A^2=-I_4$! Consequently, $$A^{15}=(A^2)^7A=(-I_4)^7A=(-1)^7I_4A=-A.$$